# what is point cut and java point in springs and where we are using in cross cutting concerns in AOP

Tags: spring

I want to know where we r using in springs these type of point cut.
I am a beginner please help me. What is the cross cutting concerns in AOP?

Answer (score 0):

A JoinPoint is any method in your app's code that you wrote whether you were using AOP or not.
An advice is code you want to run when that JoinPoint method is being called, without adding the code directly into your app's method.
An Aspect is the class that holds the advice code.
Check this for more details : http://www.coderanch.com/t/465799/Spring/Joinpoint-Pointcut

Answer (score 0):

Pointcut, join points and advice, are all expressions from AOP terminology. This language is not something that origins from Spring.
In order to understand pointcuts, one needs the be familiar with other AOP features as well.
**Advice** is the job/task assigned to an aspect. Advice defines "what" and "when" of the aspect. There are 5 kinds of advice in Spring: Before, After, After-returning, After-throwing and Around.
**Join points** are points in the execution of the application where an aspect can be plugged in (opportunities for advice to be applied).
**Pointcuts** help narrow down the join points advised by an aspect. Pointcuts defines the "where" of the aspect.
An **aspect** is the merger of advice and pointcuts.